# My template class's ctor takes a callable object as an argument but cannot be initialized from it?

Tags: c++, std-function

I've been asked to implement a desktop calculator using `std::function` through a Function table for binary operators only. So I have this code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int, int)>> binOp;
    binOp["+"] = [](int a, int b){return a + b;};
    binOp["*"] = [](int a, int b){return a * b;};

    binOp["-"] = [](int a, int b){return a - b;};

    binOp["/"] = [](int a, int b){return a / b;};

    binOp["%"] = [](int a, int b){return a % b;};

    for(const auto& p : binOp)
        std::cout << 9 << " " << p.first << " " << 8 << " = " << p.second(9, 8) << std::endl;

}
```

* The program works fine for binary operators for integer operands. What I thought to make my class template to be generic which handles different types of operands `int, double, std::string...` So I've tried this on my own with the help of `decltype`:

```
template <typename T>
struct BinOp
{
    BinOp() = default;
    BinOp(T f) : fn(f){}
    std::function<T> fn;
    using arg_type = decltype(fn(0, 0));
    arg_type operator()(arg_type a, arg_type b){return fn(a, b);}
};


int main()
{

    std::map<std::string, BinOp<int(int, int)>> calc;
    calc["+"] = BinOp<int(int, int)>([](int x, int y){return x + y;});
    calc["*"] = BinOp<int(int, int)>([](int x, int y){return x * y;});
    calc["-"] = BinOp<int(int, int)>([](int x, int y){return x - y;});
    calc["/"] = BinOp<int(int, int)>([](int x, int y){return x / y;});
    calc["%"] = BinOp<int(int, int)>([](int x, int y){return x % y;});

    for(const auto& e : calc)
        std::cout << 10 << " " << e.first << " " << 12 <<
        " = " << e.second(10, 12) << endl;

    //BinOp<std::string(std::string, std::string)> bstr = [](string s1, string s2){return s1 + s2;}; // it doesn't work?

    BinOp<std::string(std::string, std::string)> bstr;
    bstr.fn = [](string s1, string s2){return s1 + s2;}; // works fine!

    std::cout << bstr("Hello ", "Wold!") << std::endl;


    std::cout << "\nDone!\n";
}
```

- So why I am not able to initialize `bstr` from a Lambda expression although class `BinOp` has a constructor that takes a callable? But assigning to `bstr` is fine: `bstr = [](){}...` // works!
- Any tip or suggestion, critic is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is no `BinOp` constructor that takes a callable in the code shown. The code also doesn't assign to `bstr`, but rather to `bstr.fn`. Your prose doesn't match your code.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I'm sorry. I'll edit it.

Comment: So should I make it: `BinOp(function<T> f) : fn(f){}`?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I'm so sorry for that I've forgotten to include all my code, Now I've edited it.

Comment: `template <typename Sig> using  BinOp = std::function<Sig>;` ?

Comment: There's a bunch of syntax errors in the code. Once fixed, [it works](https://rextester.com/GGI76323)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: It didn't work but if I change the implementation of the ctor  to `BinOp(std::function<T> f) : fn(f){}` works but `BinOp(T f) : fn(f){}` doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me. Show the actual code you compile, and the exact and complete text of any error messages.

Comment: `template<typename T> using BinOp = std::function<T(T,T)>;`

Comment: `BinOp<std::string(std::string, std::string)> bstr {[](string s1, string s2){return s1 + s2;}};` works.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: But I want to initialize an object of class `BinOp` directly.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Really amazing! But why that works for a direct initialization but not for a copy-initialization?

Comment: @Maestro Possibly because you are asking the compiler to make two conversions that way, and it won't do that.  But I'm not certain.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Really amazing! I think so. Because as I've already read: a constructor that takes one argument provides an implicit conversion but only one conversion.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Please add the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use direct initialisation here to construct a `BinOp` directly:

```
BinOp<std::string(std::string, std::string)> bstr {[](string s1, string s2){return s1 + s2;}};
```

The reason why your original code won't compile is likely because you are asking the compiler to perform two conversions, and that it won't do.

Comment: Thank you that really useful! (you didn't give some tips about my attempts on `BinOp` or advice).

Comment: Seems OK to me.  It depends on what you plan to do with it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I only try to understand and use anything I learn.